# Find array value with based upon its index (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which finds a position in an array using Application.Match. But how do I do it the other way round: find a value in an array based on a position?

Comment: what array? how do you declare it? Is it index based array? need more information

Comment: `If Ar(i) = Value` When `i` is the position and `Value` you want to search. Assumption: It's 1D Array

Comment: it is a 1D array "posArr () As Variant". so if the array contains "milk, coke, water" and i want to find the value in position 3 ill "Ar(3) = posArr"?

Comment: One moment posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> it is a 1D array "posArr () As Variant". so if the array contains "milk, coke, water" and i want to find the value in position 3 ill "Ar(3) = posArr"? –  GodAtum 8 mins ago

Further to my example, see these two examples.

**Finding out what is at position 3**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim posArr
    Dim s As String
    Dim pos As Long

    pos = 3 '~~> 3rd Position

    s = "milk,coke,water"
    posArr = Split(s, ",")

    Debug.Print posArr(pos - 1)
End Sub
```

**Checking if the value at position 3 is "water"**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim posArr
    Dim s As String
    Dim pos As Long

    pos = 3 '~~> 3rd Position

    s = "milk,coke,water"
    posArr = Split(s, ",")

    If posArr(pos - 1) = "water" Then MsgBox "What an awesome guess!"
End Sub
```

The reason why we do `- 1` because the lowest bound is `0`

Comment: So in my code I have an array which gets the position using Application.Match (arrItem). Using your code do I: Debug.Print posArr(pos arrItem)?

Comment: `Debug.Print posArr(arrItem-1)`